# extra else with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

This sample gives me `! Extra \else.
l.6 \else` and I don't see why. It is caused by line 5 and the sample is fine if I pull it out of the if or invert the logic, so the `\setdefaultlanguage` isn't followed by `\else`. Why is this happening?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{german}
\else
   \PackageError{foo}{Cannot build with (pdf-)latex}{Use Xelatex or Lualatex}
   \stop
\fi
```

Comment: with xelatex in texlive2013 I get no error and just reach the * prompt typing `\stop` exits cleanly

Comment: I too have no problem. It should be `\expandafter\stop`, anyway, so the conditional is properly terminated before the job ends in case the false branch is followed.

Comment: This is puzzling, I also use texlive 2013. Any idea where to start debugging this?

Comment: @Max try `tlmgr update --all`

Comment: This is an archlinux without `tlmgr`, I guess I need to take it up with the maintainer, though I don't really know what to tell them

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your example and add the result? You find the relevant information in the log file after `**File list**`

Comment: I have `polyglossia.sty    2013/06/27 v1.33.4 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX and LuaTeX`

Comment: Ok I have
polyglossia 2013/05/28 v1.33.3 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX and LuaTeX
And searching the bug tracker I found this 
https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/50

So I guess the issue is solved, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved with a software update